error:Task: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.scripting.xslt.XSLTResponseWriter'
while upgrading solr from 8.11.3-slim to 9-slim I am getting error "Task: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.scripting.xslt.XSLTResponseWriter'"
I tried upgrading to 8.11.3-slim from 9.11.3-slim. It worked fine
